# how to use linq to convert list of string,<t> into XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get link to convert data into XML.
The LINQ expression i have almost working is:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
lstEmailData.Select(i => new XElement("Data",
                            new XAttribute("URL", i.WebPage ),
                                new XAttribute("emails", i.Emails.ToArray()  + " , ")
)));
```

where lstEmailData is defined as:

```
List<PageEmail> lstEmailData = new List<PageEmail>();
lstEmailData.Add(new PageEmail("site2", new List<string>() {
    "MyHotMail@NyTimes.com", "contact_us@ml.com" }));
```

where PageEmail is:

```
class PageEmail
{
    public string WebPage { get; set; }
    public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
    public PageEmail(string CurWebPage, List<string> CurEmails)
    {
        this.WebPage = CurWebPage;
        this.Emails = CurEmails;
    }
}
```

the XML output from the LINQ is off, I'm not getting the email list:

```
<contacts>
  <Data URL="site1" emails="System.String[] , " />
  <Data URL="site2" emails="System.String[] , " />
</contacts>
```

> How to get each of the i.Emails into their own xml nodes?

Comment: figured it out by this article:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx

Comment: XElement xml = new XElement("SiteData",
            lstEmailData.Select(i => new XElement("WebSite",
                                        new XAttribute("URL", i.WebPage),
                                            from o in i.Emails 
                                            select new XElement("mail", o.ToString() )
            )));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object as a second argument to the `XAttribute` constructor. It calls the `ToString` method on it. The result of calling `ToString` on an array is the array's name (So you get `System.String[]`)  To show the strings inside it, you should do use `String.Join` instead.

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
lstEmailData.Select(i => new XElement("Data",
                            new XAttribute("URL", i.WebPage ),
                                new XAttribute("emails", String.Join(",", i.Emails))
)));
```

---

> How to get each of the i.Emails into their own xml nodes?
>   Try this:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
    lstEmailData.Select(pageEmail =>
        new XElement("Data", new XAttribute("Url",pageEmail.WebPage), 
            pageEmail.Emails.Select(email => new XElement("Email",email))
        )
    )
);
```

Results:

```
<contacts>
  <Data Url="site2">
    <Email>MyHotMail@NyTimes.com</Email>
    <Email>contact_us@ml.com</Email>
  </Data>
</contacts>
```

Comment: how do i get each i.email into its own xml node?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771500/converting-array-of-objects-to-xml-in-c-sharp

Comment: I got the basic serialization working, but only need to get some recursive style action for the email list of the objects or I can get the email links but lost the site url. Is the answer two nested linq statements?

Comment: How do you want to results to be? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: each of the i.Emails into their own xml nodes <url site="me@site.com"> <email>m@m.com</email><email>a@a.com</email></url>

Comment: url node is also inside Data node?

Comment: Check my answer now. I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to store all the emails in `emails` attribute.
Use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):-

```
new XAttribute("emails", String.Join(",", i.Emails)
```

Comment: how do i get each i.email into its own xml node?

Comment: @kacalapy - Hey missed out your comment, I tried it now but with `List<string>` I am getting `<email>e1,e2,e3<email>` i.e. all the email separated by comma. Is your problem fixed?