# C# Serialize an object with a list of objects in it

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

In C# if I serialize an object that has a list of objects in it will it also serialize the list?

Example

```
public class Move {
    public string MoveName {get;  set;}

    public List<Tag> oTags = new List<Tag>;
}

public class Tag {
    public string TagName {get; set;}
}
```

If I serialize move will all the tags stored in move get serialized as well? Also if it will not serialize the list how would I go about making it do that?

```
<Move>
  <MoveName>name</MoveName>
  <Tag>Value</Tag>
  ...
</Move>
```

Comment: Regardless of the current answers, _how_ are you serializing it? For example, if you use the `XmlSerializer`, it will work. (though you may have to use some special attributes or creativity to get the specific XML schema output you want)

Comment: I am using XmlSerializer

Comment: How do you want the schema? It seems a bit ambiguous how you handle many tags. Should it be `<Move><MoveName>name</MoveName><Tag>Value1</Tag><Tag>Value2</Tag>...<Tag>ValueN</Tag></Move>`? Also, are you flexible with changing your `Move` and `Tag` classes?

Comment: Well I was simplifying the setup because really I was just looking for an answer to whether serialization would dig through my list in my object which is the desired effect in my case.

Comment: Additionally, check if object has added in the list (possible bug?!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it will serialize a `List<T>` so long as `T` (or in your case `Tag`) is serializable.

```
Move move = new Move { MoveName = "MyName" };
move.oTags.Add(new Tag { TagName = "Value1" } );
move.oTags.Add(new Tag { TagName = "Value2" } );
move.oTags.Add(new Tag { TagName = "Value3" } );

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
var writer = new StringWriter(output);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Move));
serializer.Serialize(writer, move);

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

This outputs using your current class structure as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Move xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <oTags>
    <Tag>
      <TagName>Value1</TagName>
    </Tag>
    <Tag>
      <TagName>Value2</TagName>
    </Tag>
    <Tag>
      <TagName>Value3</TagName>
    </Tag>
  </oTags>
  <MoveName>MyName</MoveName>
</Move>
```

I'll see if I can find a way to match your current XML schema, but you can look up how to apply [XmlAttributes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes) and play around with it yourself.

---

EDIT:

If you change your class declaration to use the following XmlAttributes, you will achieve the exact XML schema as in your example:

```
public class Move 
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string MoveName {get; set;}

    [XmlElement(Order = 2, ElementName = "Tags")]
    public List<Tag> oTags = new List<Tag>();
}

public class Tag 
{
    [XmlText]
    public string TagName {get; set;}
}
```

Which when serialized will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Move xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MoveName>MyName</MoveName>
  <Tags>Value1</Tags>
  <Tags>Value2</Tags>
  <Tags>Value3</Tags>
</Move>
```

Comment: Although that doesn't match what I am looking for scheme wise it does answer my question of whether it will dig through the list in my object I am serializing. The link Brendan Hill posted gives me a pretty good idea how to set it up for the layout I want. Thank you.

Comment: @maxinfet: Check my edit/update, I found a set of attributes that will produce an output that matches your schema.

Comment: @maxinfet: Also, I botched my serialization code slightly, so maybe re-check it if you had already copy/pasted it.

Comment: can you check this problem too if possible ty : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490161/how-to-serialize-listlistobject

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your class Declarations are right in your Question ? 
you are just declaring `Public Move`,  It should be `Public class Move`

Try this code

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
```

In Your case

```
Move m = new Move();
            m.oTags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = "X" });
            m.oTags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = "XX" });

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Move));
            System.IO.Stream s;

            var xmlwriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create("C:\\MXL.txt"); 
            x.Serialize(xmlwriter, m);
```

**OutPut**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Move xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <oTags>
<Tag>
  <TagName>X</TagName>
</Tag>
<Tag>
   <TagName>XX</TagName>
</Tag>
</oTags></Move>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, no it won't, since the items within the list may not be serializable.

If they are, then you may find the following page userful:

[XML Serialize generic list of serializable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212742/xml-serialize-generic-list-of-serializable-objects)