# C# object to xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have json string which is deserialized into c# class object, now I am trying serialize it into xml and writing same to the xml file. It does not have any errors or exceptioins but unable to write on xml file. The class has array of objects
Below is my code:
This is class:

```
public class WorkspaceRootObject
    {
        public WorkspaceRootObject() 
        {

        }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string contextId { get; set; }

    }
```

This is serialization:

```
        //deserializing json

        wso= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<WorkspaceRootObject>>(finalResponse);
        Console.WriteLine("after deserializing...");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\Rohit_VisualStudio\\ServerManagementFormRest\\bin\\Debug\\WorkSpaceDetails.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        //serializing into xml
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<WorkspaceRootObject>), new System.Type[] {typeof(WorkspaceRootObject)});
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        xs.Serialize(sw, wso);
```

I have used Newtonsoft json. and after opening xml file it shows Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'file:///D:/ProjectLocation/...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Serialize generic list of serializable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212742/xml-serialize-generic-list-of-serializable-objects)

Comment: Do you get any exceptions from c#? getting any errors? I can imagen you cant deserialize list bacuase there can only be one root element?

Comment: You cannot have an array at the root level of an xml serializer.  So this line is invalid : XmlSerializer(typeof(List<WorkspaceRootObject>).  Workspace cannot be a List<>.

Comment: I used pre-created List of objects and your code is working for me. So if your Deserializing is OK are you sure it's not related to the user permissions?

Comment: I am trying to serialize class object into xml. and its not related to user permissions.

Comment: is my code corret or am I going in wrong way

Comment: your created code of xml serialize works like charm, problem is not in there

Comment: why it is not writing to xml file ?