# How to create node in loop in XmlDocument using ASP.Net C#?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I am trying to create Xml file. I want to create node in loops

1. Below code what i make it to create

   ```
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(           
        new XElement("Bill",
            new XElement("ITEM",
                new XElement("Mat",
                    new XElement("ID","1"),
                    new XElement("Code"),
                    new XElement("Name")
                ),//Mat
                new XElement("Store",
                    new XElement("ID","1"),
                    new XElement("Code"),
                    new XElement("Name")
                )
            )//ITEM
        )//Bill
    );

    doc.save("Test.xml");
   ```

**Output**

```
<Bill>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <ITEM>
        <Mat>
            <ID>1<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
        </Mat>
        <Store>
            <ID>1<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
       </Store>
    </ITEM>
</Bill>
```

**I need to be like below Output**

```
<Bill>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <ITEM>
        <Mat>
            <ID>1<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
        </Mat>
        <Store>
            <ID>1<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
       </Store>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <Mat>
            <ID>2<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
        </Mat>
        <Store>
            <ID>2<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
       </Store>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <Mat>
            <ID>3<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
        </Mat>
        <Store>
            <ID>3<ID/>
            <Code />
            <Name />
       </Store>
    </ITEM>
</Bill>
```

**Note**

```
I will get the value from db and pass it to xml nodes of (ID,Code,Name). I want to iterate in loop..
```

Comment: Why not create a List with a class and serialize it to xml? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212742/xml-serialize-generic-list-of-serializable-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is image of results

[image]

You are using XDocument (not xmlDocument) which is xml linq.  Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><BILL></BILL>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);

            XElement bill = doc.Root;
            bill.Add(new XElement("version","1.0"));

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                XElement item = new XElement("ITEM");
                bill.Add(item);

                item.Add(new XElement("Mat", new object[] {
                    new XElement("ID",i),
                    new XElement("Code"),
                    new XElement("Name")
                }));

                item.Add(new XElement("Store", new object[] {
                    new XElement("ID",i),
                    new XElement("Code"),
                    new XElement("Name")
                }));
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```